# How do I calculate the standard deviation of a table in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table of returns that I want to calculate standard deviation on. My columns look like

```
`day1`day2`day3
```

How can I calculate the standard deviation of each column efficiently?

I know there's a dev function. However, unlike avg, dev cannot be called on the entire table
Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the code that you have attempted so far and the problem(s) that you encountered with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `dev` doesn't support a table as input but you can use `dev` on individual columns in a select query:

```
q)t:([]day1:til 10;day2:2*til 10;day3:3*til 10)
q)t
day1 day2 day3
--------------
0    0    0
1    2    3
2    4    6
3    6    9
4    8    12
5    10   15
6    12   18
7    14   21
8    16   24
9    18   27

q)select dev day1, dev day2, dev day3 from t
day1     day2     day3
--------------------------
2.872281 5.744563 8.616844
```

Edt: If unsure how to create a dynamic query with functional form use parse:

```
q)parse"select dev day1 from t"

?
`t
()
0b
(,`day1)!,(dev;`day1)
```

It is useful for creating the code for multiple columns:

```
// [table;where;by;cols]
?[t;();0b;

    raze { (enlist x)!enlist (dev;x) } each `day1`day2`day3]

day1     day2     day3
--------------------------
2.872281 5.744563 8.616844
```

or since you have 100+ columns, use `cols` with `except` to get all columns you want to get the standard deviation of and ignore the columns you don't

```
?[t;();0b;

    raze { (enlist x)!enlist (dev;x) } each except[cols[t];`columns`to`ignore]
```

Comment: Is there a systematic way of doing this by any chance, because what if I have 100+ columns. Select one by on will be too much work

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If your table is "flippable" then you could do:

```
q)enlist dev each flip t
day1     day2     day3
--------------------------
2.872281 5.744563 8.616844
```